# In the R mice package, how do I find the number of nodes in the tree used in my imputation?

Tags: r, tree, imputation, r-mice

In a paper under review, I have a very large dataset with a relatively small number of imputations. The reviewer asked me to report how many nodes were in the tree I generated using the CART method within MICE. I don't know why this is important, but after hunting around for a while, my own interest is piqued.
Below is a simple example using this method to impute a single value. How many nodes are in the tree that the missing value is being chosen from? And how many members are in each node?

```
data(whiteside, package ="MASS")
data <- whiteside
data[1,2] <- NA
library(mice)
impute <- mice(data,m=100,method="cart")
impute2 <- complete(impute,"long")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, `whiteside` is only used as an example here. So your actual data looks different.

I can't easily get the number of nodes for the tree generated in mice. The first problem is, that it  isn't just one tree ... as the package names says mice - Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations. Which means you are sequentially creating multiple CART trees. Also each incomplete variable is imputed by a separate model.

From the mice documentation:

> The mice package implements a method to deal with missing data. The package creates multiple imputations (replacement values) for multivariate missing data. The method is based on Fully Conditional Specification, where each incomplete variable is imputed by a separate model.

If you really want to get numbers of nodes for each used model, you probably would have to adjust the mice package itself and add some logging there.

Here is how you might approach this:

Calling `impute <- mice(data,m=100,method="cart")` you get a S3 object of class `mids` that contains information about the imputation. (but not the number of nodes for each tree)

But you can call `impute$formulas`, `impute$method`, `impute$nmis` to get some more information, which formulas were used and which variables actually had missing values.

From the `mice.impute.cart` documentation you can see, that `mice` uses `rpart` internally for creating the classification and regression trees.

Since the `mids` object does not contain information about the fitted trees I'd suggest, you use `rpart` manually with the formula from `impute$formulas`.

Like this:

```
library("rpart")
rpart(Temp ~ 0 + Insul + Gas, data = data)
```

Which will print / give you the nodes/tree. This wouldn't really be the tree used in mice. As I said, mice means multiple chained equations / multiple models after each other - meaning multiple possibly different trees after each other.  (take a look at the algortihm description here https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-cart.html for the univariate missingness case with CART). But this could at least be an indicator, if applying rpart on your specific data provides a useful model and thus leads to good imputation results.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I guess what I want is a 'typical' tree, which this should do. Also, with the Whiteside data you can do many, many imputations and work backward from the results to infer the trees, but my own data are too large for that.